# Filter list of URLs based on content headers

Tags: bash, curl

I have a list of URLs, and I would like to only keep the ones that return a certain content header. The way I am trying this is:

```
$ cat url_list | tee [???] | xargs curl -sIL | grep -qiE 'Content-Type: text' && echo [???]
```

but I don't know what to do for the [???] in tee and echo. I think the solution will use process substitution or file descriptors, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: Not the right approach for the task at hand. Use a loop, not a pipeline.

Comment: See also [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/144918)

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the XY problem, which is why I included all the context. I appreciate your full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs` is the wrong tool for this job -- and when you don't use it, you don't need `tee` either.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create an array called text_urls
text_urls=( )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if curl -sIL "$line" | grep -qiE 'Content-Type: text'; then
    text_urls+=( "$line" )
  fi
done <url_list

# Demonstrate the data stored in that array variable
echo "The following ${#text_urls[@]} URLs have Content-Type: text --"
printf '  %s\n' "${text_urls[@]}"
```

See [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) describing the `while read` loop, and [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) describing why pipelines make storing data as variables harder.